# Получить в JavaScript содержимого тега, минуя cross-origin

Tags: javascript, cross-origin

Добрый день.

Существует ли возможность получить содержимое картинки (в виде base64 или dataURL), как-либо игнорируя cross-origin polycy в броузере?

Так, например, код ([песочница здесь](http://jsfiddle.net/chernomyrdin/vLfa740L/)):

```
function dataURL (src, callback) {
   var img = new Image;

   img.onload = function () {
       var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

       canvas.width = img.width;
       canvas.height = img.height;
       canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0);
       try {
           callback(canvas.toDataURL());
       } catch (e) {
           alert(e);
       }
   };
   img.src = src;
}
// Используем
dataURL(
    "http://a.disquscdn.com/uploads/users/10355/3829/avatar92.jpg?1413802608",
    function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
);
```

Не работает, а выдает ошибку: `The operation is insecure. code: "18"`

Comment: Нет, только включенный CORS решит эту проблему.

Comment: Так же, как и proxy с CORS решает проблему. :-)

Comment: Так зачем спрашиваете, если знаете ответ? CORS обойти никак, на то он и CORS.

Comment: Возможно, я знаю не все. :-(

Возможно, что-то упустил из последних нововведений в HTML5, раньше с file-upload было сложно, а теперь createObjectURL/FormData и пр.